# Is it ok to go below basal metabolic rate to lose weight?

Tags: body-fat, bodyweight

I’m really confused. Test case: a 35 y.o. Male 5’10. Healthy. 180 lbs. 26% body fat. Ideal weight should be 160 lbs based on online TDEE calculator.

1. Downloaded this app called “Lose It”. It tells me that I should consume 1,500 calories a day to lose 2 lbs per week as a safe minimum. They say 1,500 is safe minimum.
2. Went to talk to “fitness expert”. They tell me that my basal metabolic rate is 1,700 calories. This means that I should **NEVER** go below 1,700 calories a day level. They recommended to consume a minimum of 1,900 calories a day + a lot of excersise.

Where is the truth? What is the true safe minimum? 1,500 or 1,900.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There wouldn't be any serious health risks from eating below your BMR but I wouldn't recommend doing it for any extended period of time, there are still downsides.

You will lose weight more rapidly, of course, but with a caloric intake that low you are likely to lose muscle aswell. I'm sure, like most people wanting to lose weight, you'd prefer to lose fat, while gaining a little muscle, or at least maintain you muscle mass. If you want to also maintain/build muscle I'd recommend you find your TDEE/maintenance calories and the go for a 300-500 calorie deficit. Obviously the weight loss will be slower but you'll be more likely maintain or (if you're exercising) possibly build a bit of muscle.

Also, when you take you caloric intake that low, I.e. below BMR, you body takes countermeasures, e.g. slowing metabolic processes, to conserve energy. This is essential lowering you BMR, meaning you're burning less calories than you may think. There are other unpleasant effects of extremely low caloric intake such as lethargy which won't be nice regardless, but will also make exercising more difficult if that's the route you want to take.

A few tips:

Eat a high protein diet; protein will help build/maintain muscle, is more filling thus helping with dieting, and has a high thermic effect meaning you body uses energy processing it.

Know the importance of sleep; sleep is when important bodily processes are at their maximum and, of course, is essential to ensure maximum energy throughout the day.